# MonoTouch.Dialog UIProgressView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, xamarin, uiprogressview

How can I implement an UIProgressView with `MonoTouch.Dialog`?

Is there a way to do it without creating a custom element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap any `UIView` into MT.D element with `UIViewElement`, but keep in mind that there is no cell reuse with that element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Progress HUB](http://components.xamarin.com/view/mbprogresshud/) from the Xamarin component catalog in my current project. With the new Xamarin Studio it's easy to install, and it has a clean and easy API to use. There are also plenty of other options in the [component catalog](http://components.xamarin.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to implement the original UIProgressView?